# How to know the version on libav on VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, libavcodec

I want to know which version of libav (avcodec) is using a particular VLC installation.

In one host VLC is unable to decode `h264` stream, but in other it works fine. 
The decoder/codec used is `avcodec` on both cases.

Comment: Encode something. Then check the metadata with mediainfo or ffmpeg. There'll be a string starting with `lavc`

Answer (score 1):

Just look for which version of `libavcodec` is installed:

```
dpkg -l "*avcodec*" | grep ii
```